# Drawing half image

Tags: iphone

Hi all i am having .png image.I want to draw only half of this image.If i call method drawInRect: on image with width being half the size of image,it will still draw the full image
in given rect.So how to draw half image

Answer (score 2):

Before calling -drawInRect, try setting a clip mask on the current context:

```
UIImage *image = // your image, let's say 100x100
CGRect drawingRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f); // adjust the origin; size has to be the image's size
CGRect clippingRect = drawingRect; // copy drawingRect...
clippingRect.size.width = 50.0f; // ...and reduce the width

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context); // save current graphics state
CGContextClipToRect(context, clippingRect);
[image drawInRect:drawingRect];
CGContextRestoreGState(context); // restore previous state (without clip mask)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's in a `UIImageView`, you can change the frame to only fit half the image, then set `[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could crop your existing image by using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect

Answer (score 0):

Clip Rect did the magic. Thanks @thomas

```
CGContextClipToRect(context, clippingRect);
```